# hook_entity_view_alter // Undefined index: #entity

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a basic module, works good returning data from a ECK bundle, though now, I've added some custom breadcrumbs using the snippet below, also works good. The only problem is, when I view other pages breadcrumbs running basic nodes, such as articles I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: #entity in theme1_entity_view_alter() (line
>   92 of htdocs/example.dev/themes/theme1/template.php). Notice: Trying
>   to get property of non-object in theme1_entity_view_alter() (line 93
>   of htdocs/example.dev/themes/theme1/template.php).

```
/**
 * hook_entity_view_alter for customise breadcrumbs
 */
function theme1_entity_view_alter(&$build)
{
    $entity = $build['#entity'];
    if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'full' && $entity->type == 'event')
    {
      $breadcrumb = array();
      $breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
      $breadcrumb[] = l('Whats on', 'whats-on');
      drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
    }
}
```

I understand that nodes are also entities, and think that hook_entity_view_alter() is also be called on nodes. If so, how do I fix this so only the entities in my bundle are altered and all other nodes ignored?

Many thanks, Barry